# How to add a number of days to a Date while skipping weekends and other holidays and start day is weekend or holiday

Tags: c#, datetime

Below code calculates the number of workdays to be added and if the end date falls on holidays/weekends, shift the date to the next day.
**But this code is on an assumption that the start date is not on weekends/holidays.**

I want the code which also works if the start date falls on a weekend/holiday.

> Please note this code was posted by 
>   ElenaSofea on 17 Jun'13 but as I was not able to comment on it asking this as a new question.
>   Reference: [How to add a number of days to a Date while skipping weekends and other holidays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653589/how-to-add-a-number-of-days-to-a-date-while-skipping-weekends-and-other-holidays?rq=1)

```
static DateTime CalculateFutureDate(DateTime fromDate, int numberofWorkDays,   
                                ICollection<DateTime> holidays)
{
    var futureDate = fromDate;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberofWorkDays; i++ )
    {
        if (futureDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday 
         || futureDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
         || (holidays != null && holidays.Contains(futureDate)))
        {
            futureDate = futureDate.AddDays(1);
            numberofWorkDays++;
        }
        else
        {
            futureDate = futureDate.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
    while(futureDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday 
         || futureDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
         || (holidays != null && holidays.Contains(futureDate)))
    {
        futureDate = futureDate.AddDays(1);
    }
    return futureDate;
}
```

Comment: you really should take a look on http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This is not a Java question. I retagged it as C# since the source code that you copied comes from a C#-tagged post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the date as input, such that this method validates to check whether it is saturday or sunday

```
public static boolean isValidateSundayorSaturday(String date) throws Exception {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();     
        if (date != null) {

            calendar.setTime(getDate(date,null));
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

            if (day == Calendar.SUNDAY || day == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Changed as per the java code base, instead of js @PaulRichter

Answer (score 0):

You've to provide all excluded dates because it is different from region to region even in same country.

If you want to see code [here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537813/number-of-days-in-date-range-excluding-weekends-and-other-dates-in-c-sharp?rq=1)